# Express.Js How to guard resources between users

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I want to make a simple web app accessible ONLY to logged in users which have routes like

```
/:userId/resourceX
```

Is there any library in order to protect every resource of each logged-in user from other logged-in users?
For example, a logged-in user with `userId=5` should not access the resource `/2/resourceX`, where 2 is the userId that belongs to another user

Comment: Basic approach might be to implement some form of authentication (e.g. cookies, JWTs, etc.) that allows you to uniquely identify users. Then, in your Express request handler, check if the ID of the user who made the request matches the ID of the user that the resource belongs to. If you opt for JWTs, you could stick the user's ID in the claims themselves. If you opt for cookies, you can stick the user's ID in the session store and send the session ID in the cookie.

Comment: Thank you very much i will check all of these options and in a few days i will come back

Comment: @chillin thank you i worked with jwt+ httponly cookie